# How to store file names that partially match by looping through the directories in R?

Tags: r

Basically this is a for loop question. I have `my.dir` containing directories `A, B and C`. A has files `apple.txt,orange.txt`; B has files `tomato.txt, carrot.txt`; C has files `cat.txt`. I also have an object (`myobject`) with file names but partially matching names.

```
my.dir<- c("A","B","C")
myobject<-c("app","ora","car","Jak")
```

Now I want to use for loop and store all the files in A,B,C that match with the names in myobject and get the `result` files. I may not use some of the directories, for example, directory C is not being used as I am not extracting anything from there in this example. I also want to keep track of the names in `myobject` that are found and not found. for example, `Jak` is not found and `app,ora` and `car` are found.

I want to get something like this in the 'result' :

```
 files    
 "apple.txt" "orange.txt" "carrot.txt"
found
"app" "ora" "car"
not found
"Jak"
```

This is what I have tried:

```
all.file.names <- {} 
for (j in 1:length(my.dir)){
  all.bam.files <- list.files(my.dir[j])
  all.bam.files <- all.bam.files[grepl(".txt$",all.bam.files)]
  all.file.names <- grep(myobject, all.bam.files, value=TRUE) 
}
```

Comment: What was the result of what you tried (an abbreviated version pointing out what worked and what didn't would suffice). Also, `list.files()` takes an argument `pattern` that you can use to only return files that match a `regex` pattern. Don't forget that you can use `list.files(...., full=TRUE)` to get the full file path; helpful for figuring out where each file was found.

Comment: My code only gives  me the file names in one directory(i assume the last directory in the loop). I don't need te full path in this case.